# Is quantum computing apropriate for video encoding?

Tags: applications

Hello and sorry if the question is too layman's here. I haven't found an answer when googling.

I am a programmer with some video encoding background, so I know how much energy is "wasted" on encoding. Especially with the 2020's situation when a lot of people are working from home, being on video calls all the time, world's encoding has dramatically increased.

There's the new H.265 encoder, which does quite a lot of optimizations, but many of them need to search through a lot of possibilities on how to describe objects moving in a scene - direction, light changes, color changes, size changes, ...

Intuitively, this seems like an ideal application of quantum computing, which, as far as I have read, is good for parallel searching for optimal solution of rather non-discrete problems.

Is that a correct assumption? Is there any progress in that direction? Or is it still too early to apply the current state of the art to such problems?

Comment: As video encoding works with huge amount of information and there are quatum processors with only lower tens of qubits, such application seems impossible today. Moreover today quantum processors are too noisy.